# Papers where protein oligomerization has been engineered away

Tags: synthetic-biology, protein-engineering

I have a protein that acts as a monomer, but appears to have a relatively high self-affinity in vivo (measured using transient transfection of a plasmid coding for the protein), which is annoying because I'm trying to engineer conditional self-association like with FRB-FKBP w/ rapamycin. Have there been any papers where self-clumping of a protein has been engineered away?

My current approach is to use threading to identify a protein structure and a docking program to identify sites of self-interaction and mutate those sites away.

Comment: “Clumping” to mean means aggregation, but it sounds like you wish to change the oligomeric state. One approach I recall used in streptavidin was to introduce charged residues at the subunit interface to create a repulsive effect. I’ll find the paper when I have a moment.

Comment: *Engineering Soluble Monomeric Streptavidin with Reversible Biotin Binding Capability*

Comment: *Stable, high-affinity streptavidin monomer for protein labeling and monovalent biotin detection*

Comment: You should define your question properly. Does "self-clumping" means oligomerization or aggregation? You should also give more details about your preparation. How do you prepare your protein, is it recombinant, it is a known protein?

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: The authors of the [dronpa protein](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/306/5700/1370), mention that the initial WT protein they identified oligomerised and they introduced mutations to stop this. However, the explanation of how/why they chose the particular mutations (only shown in the supplements) is lacking.

Comment: You have not provided enough information to support your statements.  In what types of experiments does it behave as a monomer (and how can one determine whether it is acting as a monomer or a higher oligomer?)? What evidence do you base your assertion that in transient transfection assays it is clumping, or aggregating, or oligomerizing?  If the pure protein is soluble, you might be able to crosslink it to a matrix and construct a affinity column.  In a mixture of cellular proteins does this protein bind specifically to such a column?